Raspberry Pi + LTE Modem: Broadcast both wireless and wired internet
My setup consists of a SIMCOM7600G-H LTE Modem hat and a raspberry pi 4 running 64-bit raspberry pi OS. The modem is all setup and supplying a connection to the OS and I've successfully setup an access point broadcasting a LAN, which I can connect all my devices to and access the internet.
But now I want to setup an additional wired connection so that my devices can access the internet either via the local WIFI connection or via a network switch which is connected to the RPI via the onboard ethernet port.
I've looked up things like interface bonds and teams, but I'm not sure if bonding the interface that supplies the internet to the Pi to the ethernet port would prevent a simultaneous wireless LAN connection.
I've searched the web and I can't really find the answer I'm looking for (but maybe I'm not looking hard enough). Would someone be able to give some tips/directions on what to do? Thanks!

So I actually managed to get it working with NetworkManager. The two key points for me were setting ipv4.method = shared for both the hotspot and the Ethernet connection and putting both connections in the same firewall zone.
Now, running nmcli con returns
Ethernet      <uuid>  ethernet   eth0   
Hotspot       <uuid>  wifi       wlan0  
LTEModem      <uuid>  ethernet   usb0 

and both wlan0 and eth0 are part of the same firewall zone. Running firewall-cmd --get-active-zones returns
nm-shared
  interfaces: eth0 wlan0
public
  interfaces: usb0

I also set connection.autoconnect: yes to ensure both eth0 and wlan0 go up when the Pi starts. Doing these two things and everything seems to magically work!

I've never tried to do what you are trying to do (forward two interfaces to one) until just now, but while I'd presume this isn't very unusual searching for an example proved mostly fruitless -- the few I did find simply did what you would do when routing one to another twice, using IP forwarding and masquerading.  I'll describe that first, then another (IMO, probably better) method using a virtual bridge.
I'm not taking into account NetworkManager or whatever master networking service you are using because I don't use them; you may want to delist all involved interfaces and just use the wpa_supplicant service to initialize the wifi.
Using IP Forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -D FORWARD -i iface1 -o iface0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D FORWARD -i iface0 -o iface1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D FORWARD -i iface2 -o iface0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D FORWARD -i iface0 -o iface2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o iface0 -j MASQUERADE

Mapping that to your context, iface0 would be the uplink modem and iface[1,2] would be the wifi and ethernet.  I did not try this, but believe it will work (if not it should be immediately obvious).
It's important that the wifi and ethernet have two separate private address ranges assigned to them, which probably means you'll need two separate instance of dhcpd running.  This is different from the next approach.  To do that manually:
ip link set iface1 up
ip addr add 10.10.1.1/24 dev iface1
ip link set iface2 up
ip addr add 10.10.2.1/24 dev iface2

Using a Software Bridge
The bonding driver looks similar to bridging, but while I haven't used the former I suspect the latter is more appropriate.  I also think bridging is tidier than a pure iptables method (eg., it should be do-able with only one dhcpd instance). The approach would be to bridge the ethernet and the wifi:
brctl addbr inpbr
brctl addif inpbr iface1
brctl addif inpbr iface2

Assign inpbr an address which will serve as the router for connecting clients:
ip addr add 10.100.0.1/24 dev inpbr

Use that to run dhcpd on inpbr, and forward/masquerade it to the modem as in the first method (but there will only be two FORWARD rules, to connect inpbr and iface0).
I did try this with two Pi's I have connected via separate ethernet ports to my desktop, sans dhcpd since they just use static addresses.  These were already bridged, but normally they both use their own wifi for the internet (since they stay on 24/7 when I shut down the big box).  I turned wifi off on one and set the default route to go through the desktop and viola, it worked, the Pi had internet access.
The potential complication I see here is hostapd, which I presume you are using for the WLAN.  With the first iptables based approach, that shouldn't matter since it is just about IP addresses and hostapd is a layer 2 beast.  However, interfaces represent the whole stack and bridging them may (or may not) cause a problem there.
Note that before they are bridged the interfaces should not have any address assigned, they should just be raised (ip link set ___ up).  There will be only one subnet, the range assigned to inpbr (meaning clients should be able to reach each other across the bridge, which I do not think will work with pure IP forwarding unless you add more masquerading).

Thanks for your very detailed response! I looked in to iptables and managed to partially get it working that way, but in the end I managed to do it with NetworkManager, which for me was a bit simpler. I also really like your bridge approach, but since I have it all working now, I don't feel like messing with it more :) Thanks again!

If you can get it done using NetworkManager it should be simpler yes (otherwise what is the point of NetworkManager?), and that is a sane choice.  I stopped using that stuff a long time ago because I had already learned network layers and commonplace protocols in school (so did not need them tucked away in a black box) and realized most of what they do is really not that complicated when done with lower level tools which are universal to linux systems (as opposed to the evolving variety of high level management services).
